# Parse error 100

Tags: parse-platform

I'm getting this error most of the time in last 24 hours. Sometimes, it works ok, without any fixes. After few requests it stops working again.
This error first appears without any changes in code. My internet connection is ok.

error in browser console in my app:

```
POST https://api.parse.com/1/classes/NewEstateData net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESETmain.js:2000
Parse._ajax.dispatchmain.js:2003
Parse._ajaxmain.js:2109
(anonymous function)main.js:4509
_.extend.then.wrappedResolvedCallbackmain.js:4571
(anonymous function)main.js:4554
_.extend.then.runLatermain.js:4570
_.extend.thenmain.js:2098
Parse._requestmain.js:8872
Parse.Query.firstmain.js:8727
Parse.Query.getmain.js:38795
Parse.Object.extend.getNewEstateByIdmain.js:36802
React.createClass.componentDidMountmain.js:17732
assign.notifyAllmain.js:30901
ON_DOM_READY_QUEUEING.closemain.js:33673
Mixin.closeAllmain.js:33614
Mixin.performmain.js:28956
batchedMountComponentIntoNodemain.js:33600
Mixin.performmain.js:26083
ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdatesmain.js:31827
batchedUpdatesmain.js:29091
ReactMount._renderNewRootComponentmain.js:30330
ReactPerf.measure.wrappermain.js:29180
ReactMount.rendermain.js:30330
ReactPerf.measure.wrappermain.js:38781
(anonymous function)main.js:15664
React.createClass.statics.run.dispatchHandlermain.js:15632
(anonymous function)main.js:14686
(anonymous function)main.js:14686
(anonymous function)main.js:14689
Transition.tomain.js:15631
(anonymous function)main.js:14668
Transition.frommain.js:15628
dispatchmain.js:15679
refreshmain.js:15675
runmain.js:16367
runRoutermain.js:38780
224../components/appmain.js:1
smain.js:1
emain.js:1
(anonymous function)
main.js:38800
getById() error null Parse.Error {code: 100, message: "XMLHttpRequest failed: {"statusText":"","status":0…null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null}"}code: 100message: "XMLHttpRequest failed: {"statusText":"","status":0,"responseURL":"","response":"","responseType":"","responseXML":null,"responseText":"","upload":{"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null},"withCredentials":false,"readyState":4,"timeout":0,"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null}"__proto__: Parse.Errorconstructor: function (code, message) {ACCOUNT_ALREADY_LINKED: 208AGGREGATE_ERROR: 600CACHE_MISS: 120COMMAND_UNAVAILABLE: 108CONNECTION_FAILED: 100DUPLICATE_VALUE: 137EMAIL_MISSING: 204EMAIL_NOT_FOUND: 205EMAIL_TAKEN: 203EXCEEDED_QUOTA: 140FILE_DELETE_ERROR: 153FILE_READ_ERROR: 601FILE_SAVE_ERROR: 130FILE_TOO_LARGE: 129INCORRECT_TYPE: 111INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR: 1INVALID_ACL: 123INVALID_CHANNEL_NAME: 112INVALID_CLASS_NAME: 103INVALID_CONTENT_LENGTH: 128INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS: 125INVALID_EVENT_NAME: 160INVALID_FILE_NAME: 122INVALID_IMAGE_DATA: 150INVALID_JSON: 107INVALID_KEY_NAME: 105INVALID_LINKED_SESSION: 251INVALID_NESTED_KEY: 121INVALID_POINTER: 106INVALID_PUSH_TIME_ERROR: 152INVALID_QUERY: 102INVALID_ROLE_NAME: 139INVALID_SESSION_TOKEN: 209LINKED_ID_MISSING: 250MISSING_CONTENT_LENGTH: 127MISSING_CONTENT_TYPE: 126MISSING_OBJECT_ID: 104MUST_CREATE_USER_THROUGH_SIGNUP: 207NOT_INITIALIZED: 109OBJECT_NOT_FOUND: 101OBJECT_TOO_LARGE: 116OPERATION_FORBIDDEN: 119OTHER_CAUSE: -1PASSWORD_MISSING: 201PUSH_MISCONFIGURED: 115REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED: 155SCRIPT_FAILED: 141SESSION_MISSING: 206TIMEOUT: 124UNSAVED_FILE_ERROR: 151UNSUPPORTED_SERVICE: 252USERNAME_MISSING: 200USERNAME_TAKEN: 202VALIDATION_ERROR: 142X_DOMAIN_REQUEST: 602arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 2name: ""prototype: Parse.Error__proto__: function Empty() {}<function scope>__proto__: Object__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__() { [native code] }__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__() { [native code] }__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__() { [native code] }__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__() { [native code] }constructor: function Object() { [native code] }hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() { [native code] }isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf() { [native code] }propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable() { [native code] }toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() { [native code] }toString: function toString() { [native code] }valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }get __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }set __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }main.js:38800
Parse.Object.extend.getNewEstateById.query.get.errormain.js:4645
(anonymous function)main.js:4533
_.extend.then.wrappedRejectedCallbackmain.js:4471
(anonymous function)main.js:522
_.each._.forEachmain.js:4470
_.extend.rejectmain.js:4549
_.extend.then.wrappedRejectedCallbackmain.js:4471
(anonymous function)main.js:522
_.each._.forEachmain.js:4470
_.extend.rejectmain.js:4539
(anonymous function)main.js:4533
_.extend.then.wrappedRejectedCallbackmain.js:4575
(anonymous function)main.js:4554
_.extend.then.runLatermain.js:4574
_.extend.thenmain.js:4536
_.extend.then.wrappedRejectedCallbackmain.js:4471
(anonymous function)main.js:522
_.each._.forEachmain.js:4470
_.extend.rejectmain.js:4549
_.extend.then.wrappedRejectedCallbackmain.js:4471
(anonymous function)main.js:522
_.each._.forEachmain.js:4470
_.extend.rejectmain.js:4539
(anonymous function)main.js:4533
_.extend.then.wrappedRejectedCallbackmain.js:4575
(anonymous function)main.js:4554
_.extend.then.runLatermain.js:4574
_.extend.thenmain.js:4536
_.extend.then.wrappedRejectedCallbackmain.js:4471
(anonymous function)main.js:522
_.each._.forEachmain.js:4470
_.extend.rejectmain.js:4516
(anonymous function)main.js:4533
_.extend.then.wrappedRejectedCallbackmain.js:4471
(anonymous function)main.js:522
_.each._.forEachmain.js:4470
_.extend.rejectmain.js:4539
(anonymous function)main.js:4533
_.extend.then.wrappedRejectedCallbackmain.js:4575
(anonymous function)main.js:4554
_.extend.then.runLatermain.js:4574
_.extend.thenmain.js:4536
_.extend.then.wrappedRejectedCallbackmain.js:4471
(anonymous function)main.js:522
_.each._.forEachmain.js:4470
_.extend.rejectmain.js:1987
Parse._ajax.xhr.onreadystatechange
```

Parse.com administrative panel - the same. Can't fetch any data, getting an error:
[image]

```
XMLHttpRequest failed: {"statusText":"","status":0,"responseURL":"","response":"","responseType":"","responseXML":null,"responseText":"","upload":{"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null},"withCredentials":false,"readyState":4,"timeout":0,"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,"onabort":null}
```

There are no excessive API requests.